# How should I fill these blanks on an agreement?

Tags: prepositions, legalese, agreement

How should I fill these blanks on an agreement?

The agreement starts like this; **__ legally represented by *_***, residing at **__ on __** hereinafter referred as "Contractor"...

1)Name

2)as the person not company herself/himself?

3)Address

4)?

Is "residing at ... on ..." a common usage? I searched but couldn't find anyting like this.

Comment: If this is proof-reading, it's off-topic.

Comment: No, it is not a proof-reading question.

Comment: I wonder if 4 is street or date

Comment: If you are having difficulty with this, the best way to fill in the blanks is to get legal advice. Really.

Comment: Looks like an interesting question. I think there should be the name after the 'by' and the address after 'on'. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Mr Smith, legally represented by Mssrs Thompson & Thomson, Solicitors / Legal Advisors Group, Ltd, residing at # 12, Nowhere Rd, London, AB01 23WW, on the 30th September 2013 (?) - on my behalf (?), hereinafter ...

You may reside (dwell permanently) *at* or *in* (or *abroad* ...)

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the "residing at  on " has two purposes.

This structure establishes identity via location and point in time.  If the specified John Smith currently resides at , and a different John Smith resided there earlier, and a third John Smith may move there in the future, this specifies which of the three it is.  It would be like recording traffic and someone said it was the silver Mercedes that went through a specific intersection.  Which silver Mercedes would be better identified with the date and time.

Once that identity is established, it allows for changes in location.  If John Smith now lives at a different address, he can still be identified as the person who lived at this address at the stated point in time.